# Rewrite the expression in the form $A \sin(x+C)$

Tags: trigonometry

Rewrite the following expression in the form $A \sin(x+C)$
$$4 \sin x + 4\sqrt{3} \cos x$$

This is what I have so far, and I'm not even sure it's the right approach.  I just dont understand this concept as a whole:

$$A \cos(c)\sin(x) + A\sin(c)\cos(x)$$

$$A\cos (c)=4$$

$$A\sin (c)=4\sqrt{3}$$

$$\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$$  ??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please let us know what work you've done towards and answer and where you are stuck.

Comment: Just realized that.

Comment: should I repost the question with my work or do it in the comments?

Comment: @cocalope Edit the question

Comment: Please make edits in the question itself.

Comment: how do you insert square roots?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: As you wrote above, $\sin(x+c) = \cos(c) \sin(x) + \sin(c) \cos(x)$. Imagine that you could find some $c$ so that $\cos(c) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin(c) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, you would then have $$\sin(x + c) = \frac{1}{2} \sin(x) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \cos(x) = \frac{1}{2} \big[\sin(x) + \sqrt{3} \cos(x)\big].$$

Comment: Oh, that was exactly my thought! +1.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your term in the form
$\sqrt{4^2+4^2\cdot 3}\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{4^2+4^2\cdot3}}\sin(x)+\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{4^2+4^2\cdot3}}\cos(x)\right)$
now we have
$\cos(\phi)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{4^4+4^2\cdot 3}}$ and 
$\sin(\phi)=\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{4^2+4^2\cdot3}}$

Comment: k so I got cos(x)=1/2 and sin(x)=(sqrt3)/2

Comment: So then 1/2 sin (x+(sqrt3)/2)  ??